# How to find attributes and their values in an XML without the name?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm new to C#

Here the xml:

```
<ROOT>
  <Columns BaseXPath="//Orders/Position/">
    <Colum XPath="@PositionSK" Name="Position"/>
    <Colum XPath="@PosGroup" Name="Gruppen-Nr"/>
    <Colum XPath="@PosNumber" Name="PositionsNr"/>
    <Colum XPath="@PositionCommercialTypeSK" Name="Status"/>
    <Colum XPath="@BundlePositionSK" Name="BundlePositionSK"/>
    <Colum XPath="@MainPositionSK" Name="MainPositionSK"/>
    <Colum XPath="@SalesAgentPrice" Name="Preis"/>
    <Colum XPath="@BookingUnitSK" Name="Buch"/>
    <Colum XPath="@ContentComponentCommSK" Name="IKO"/>
    <Colum XPath="@PositionTypeSK" Name="PositionsTyp"/>
    <Colum XPath="//Advertisement[@AdvertisementSK = PositionAdvertisementRelationship/@AdvertisementSK]/@AdvertisementSK" Name="AdvertisementSK"/>
    <Colum XPath="//Advertisement[@AdvertisementSK = PositionAdvertisementRelationship/@AdvertisementSK]/@AdvertisementTypeSK" Name="Formatvorgabe"/>
  </Columns>
</ROOT>
```

This xml can always change. So its never the same. Sometimes there are more infos, sometimes less.

This xml give me the certain info, which should be searched in the second "main xml".

So now I know that I have to find the Attribute of PositionSK, PosGroup, PositionCommercialTypeSK, ... . In the other xml.

But how can I do this? The name is never the same, so I need a placeholder for them?

I tried this:

```
public class ResultNames
{
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

    public List<ResultNames> GetRightNames (string file)
    {
        xml.Load(file); //this is the xml file

        var list = xml.SelectNodes("//ROOT/Columns/Colum");

        foreach ( XmlNode colum in list)
        {
            XmlNode bla = colum.Attributes; //I dont know what I can do here, without any name.
        }

        return null;
    }
```

and what is with the other xml file, do I need an extra class?

A small sample from the other xml:

```
<Set>
  <Orders OrderSK="0013233309" OrderTypeSK="ORDER" OrderDate="2000-01-01T12:00:00" OrderPrice="0.0000" OrderQuantity="0.00" DistrictSK="0026070180" PaymentTypeSK="E" OrderCreationTypeSK="SNW5ORD" SalesAgentSK="0020025518" ChangeDate="2018-01-25T15:48:29" SalesOrganisationSK="K10-100-1000-50-65" ChangeDateFS="2017-12-11T15:25:21" Source="CORE" Status="C">
    <Position PosNumber="3" PosGroup="5" PositionTypeSK="ONL" PositionCommercialTypeSK="DEFAULT"
```

But its a lot bigger.

Comment: It looks to me that this XML gives you everything you need in the form of XPATHs. `BaseXPath` tells you what represents the "rows" (I think), just select everything that matches that XPATH.  Then use the `XPATH` in the `Column` elements to select the attributes from that row item.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the *other* XML document looks like?

Comment: @BradleyUffner I've tried. But the other xml is soooo big. And i want to put these outputs in a DataGridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Xml Linq along with a dictionary

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME1 = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FILENAME2 = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME1);

            Dictionary<string, XElement> dict = doc.Descendants("Columns").FirstOrDefault().Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("XPath"), y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            XDocument order = XDocument.Load(FILENAME2);
            List<XElement> positions = order.Descendants("Position").ToList();

            foreach (XElement position in positions)
            {
                foreach (XAttribute attribute in position.Attributes())
                {
                    string name = attribute.Name.LocalName;
                    string value = (string)attribute;

                    XElement element = dict["@" + name];
                    element.SetValue(value);


                }
            }



        }
    }

}
```

---

Code below just gets the Name from first Xml file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME1 = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FILENAME2 = @"c:\temp\test1.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME1);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = doc.Descendants("Columns").FirstOrDefault().Elements()
                .GroupBy(x => (string)x.Attribute("XPath"), y => (string)y.Attribute("Name"))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

            XDocument order = XDocument.Load(FILENAME2);
            List<XElement> positions = order.Descendants("Position").ToList();

            foreach (XElement position in positions)
            {
                foreach (XAttribute attribute in position.Attributes())
                {
                    string name = attribute.Name.LocalName;
                    string value = (string)attribute;

                    if(dict.ContainsKey("@" + name))
                    {
                       string xName = dict["@" + name];
                       Console.WriteLine("Key = '{0}', Name = '{1}'", name, xName);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not in dictionary : Key = '{0}'", name);
                    }
                }
            }



        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So, I put in the Dictionary both of the xml files?

Comment: Nothing in the posting spoke about two xml files.  Are you trying to compare the xml files?  I would make two dictionaries if you are comparing.  Then you can use a JOIN (or Left outer Join) by dictionary keys to compare.

Comment: yes of course I talk about two xml files.. read again :) I want to search after the infos from the first xml file in the second. But the Words can always be changed.

Comment: Read you posting again.  There is no word 'second'.  All you say is : "Sometimes there are more infos".

Comment: Yeah thats right. In the first xml there can sometimes be more infos or less. And these infos I want so search in the second "main xml". Sorry if its confusing.

Comment: I update code to take values from 2nd file and put into first.

Comment: ehm.. stupid beginner question.. :D I have a method which is called "GetRightNames" and I have to give something back at the end of my method. **return ...** so what do I have to return here? return element?

Comment: Do you need the Element or just the string?  I changed to XElement in case you need to change the value in the first Xml file.  If you do not need to change anything in the first file then use my original code with the string.

Comment: No, guess I don't need to change anything. I want that the method gives me all the infos **PositionSK, PosGroup, PositionCommercialTypeSK, ...** back with the right value. So I have to give a list back, or not?

Comment: How can I change it that it give me just the things from the first xml file, and not all? That it gives me these 12 things and not any more info?
Your answer works, but shows too much :D
And I need the "Name" from the xml file.

Comment: I posted old code that just got Name from first xml file.

Comment: Thank you! But `string xName = dict["@" + name];` returned always null.. And know it gives me still all the elements of the second xml and not just "PositionSK, PosGroup, PosNumber, PositionCommercialTypeSK, BundlePositionSK, MainPositionSK, SalesAgentPrice, BookingUnitSK, ContentComponentCommSK, PositionTypeSK"

Comment: Name is an attribute, not an element.  So I changed the dictionary in 2nd example.

Comment: Ahh, still confusing with the element, attribute things.. :D
So there's one problem left.. "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: Key not in Dictonary"
Because in the list there are more attributes, and then this exception comes. What can I do?

Comment: Test to see if item is in dictionary.  If item is not in first xml file (and dictionary), all you can do is display a warning message.  I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make some assumptions about the data you are working with, since you haven't provided examples of everything.

The first assumption is the format of the 2nd XML document.  I had to guess from the format of the first document.

The 2nd assumption is that that XPATHs specified in the 1st document `Colum` elements always point to an `Attribute`.

```
void Main()
{
    string xml1 =
@"<ROOT>
  <Columns BaseXPath=""//Orders/Position/"">
    <Colum XPath=""@PositionSK"" Name=""Position""/>
    <Colum XPath=""@PosGroup"" Name=""Gruppen-Nr""/>
  </Columns>
</ROOT>";

    string data =
@"<Set>
    <Orders>
        <Position PositionSK=""A"" PosGroup=""1"" SomeOtherAttribute=""ABC"" />
        <Position PositionSK=""B"" PosGroup=""2"" SomeOtherAttribute=""DEF"" />
    </Orders>
</Set>";

    var schemaDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml1);
    var dataDoc = XDocument.Parse(data);

    var itemsXPath = schemaDoc.Descendants("Columns").FirstOrDefault()?.Attribute("BaseXPath").Value;

    var basePath = schemaDoc.Descendants("Columns").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("BaseXPath").Value;
    // XPATH isn't supposed to end with a trailing "/".
    if (basePath.EndsWith("/"))
    {
        basePath = basePath.Substring(0, basePath.Length - 1);
    }
    var lines = dataDoc.XPathSelectElements(basePath);

    var rowIndex = 0;
    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"---Row {rowIndex}");
        foreach (var col in schemaDoc.Descendants("Colum"))
        {
            var columnName = col.Attribute("Name").Value;
            Console.Write($"{columnName}: ");

            var columnValue = ((XAttribute)((IEnumerable<Object>)line.XPathEvaluate(col.Attribute("XPath").Value)).FirstOrDefault()).Value;
            Console.WriteLine(columnValue);
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
        rowIndex++;
    }
}
```

This produces the following output:

> ---Row 0
>   Position: A
>   Gruppen-Nr: 1
>
> ---Row 1
>   Position: B
>   Gruppen-Nr: 2

You can change the attributes that are output by adjusting the content of `xml1`.

Comment: Guess that wouldn't work, cause the other xml file is just too big.

Comment: It works for me based on the new examples you gave.  The document size shouldn't matter, unless it is literally too big to fit in to memory.  How  large *is* the file anyway?

Comment: like 2583 lines with a length of 671994. And I want the output in a DGV.

Comment: This seem like an odd question, but you aren't talking about adding your xml content to the code as a `string` the way I did in the example, right?  In your real application you would obviously want to load it from a file instead of a string.

Comment: 2583 lines is nothing, it should easily handle that.  This is just an example of how to read the data, you can do whatever you want with the name of the field, and the column values, including adding them to a datagrid.

Comment: okay thank you, I will try this :) But why do you say "var itemsXPath = schemaDoc.Descendants("Columns").FirstOrDefault()?.Attribute("BaseXPath").Value;" and "var basePath = schemaDoc.Descendants("Columns").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("BaseXPath").Value;" is that not nearly the same?

Comment: Leaving it out was just a typo from typing quickly.  `?.` is the "[null propagation operator](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/16101a/null-propagation-operator-a-new-feature-of-C-Sharp-6-0/)".  It differs slightly from `.` in that it won't throw a null reference exception if the value to the left is `null`, instead the `null` is just propagated (or moved) to the left.  In this case, it was an attempt to make the line "Safer" in case there is no `Column` element.  It isn't really needed in my example, because if its missing, other things go horribly wrong.

Comment: This is a *lot* of safety checking that is missing from my example to make it fully complete and robust against errors.  Ideally, you would want to verify that things are not `null` and contain expected variable types at a few different places, just in case that data isn't what you expected, so that the application doesn't crash.

Comment: It always says that if I try to parse it "var schemaDoc = XDocument.Parse(file);" that something is wrong in the xml file on position 1, 1. But its just the xml file? What is wrong there?

Comment: Use `XDocument.Load(filename)` to read from a file. `XDocument.Parse` loads the `XDocument` from a `string` containing the xml.

Comment: The dictionary is a List of KeyValuePairs()<string,object>.  The key is a hash table that allows quick lookup.  In this case the keys from 1st xml and are : '@PositionSK', '@PosGroup', ...  I can remove the '@' if you do not need them.

Comment: @jdweng yeah I don't need the '@' .. and in your solution it gave me all names and values from the second xml file, and not only those from the first xml.

Comment: I don't think that simply stripping off the `@` and using it as a lookup will give you the result you want, or at least not the *full* result that the first XML file is capable of representing.  The first XML file contains `XPATH` complex strings that look like `//Advertisement[@AdvertisementSK = PositionAdvertisementRelationship/@AdvertisementSK]/@AdvertisementSK`, which will actually require full `XPATH` parsing, and DOM navigation to produce correct values.  These are not simply pointing directly to attributes of the elements in the 2nd file.  You also state that the first XML...

Comment: ... can contain a wide variety of data that you can't predict.  It is possible, in the future, that it may contain something other than a simple `XPATH` attribute lookup, or something new, that hasn't been seen before.  The fact that the attribute is named `XPath` suggests that it will always be a valid XPath string though.

Comment: Do you need anything changed?

Comment: yeah, but it would help, if I have an approach for this.. So that it gives me all the elements with values. till the last two.